# Cannot Find what is causing this : Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs

So after looking over many different questions asking the about this warning, I have found that there is not one single reason why this would be occurring making it difficult to infer a solution on my own code.

So here is my code incase anyone has another pair of eyes they can put on it and spot maybe why i would be getting this error.

This error occurs when not on first arrival of the component but after leaving and returning to it again.

I have a smart container and a dumb component set up so here is the container:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrders, listUseCases } from '../../actions/order';
import { storeWithExpiration } from '../../utils/common.js';

import OrdersIndex from './OrdersIndex';

export class OrdersIndexContainer extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    account: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    orders: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    platformMap: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    progress: PropTypes.number,
    listOrdersAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    listUseCasesAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { orders, platformMap, progress } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <OrdersIndex
          orders={ orders }
          platformMap={ platformMap }
          progress={ progress }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderOrderIndex = () => {

  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    const { account, listOrdersAction, listUseCasesAction } = this.props;
    const token = storeWithExpiration.get('token');
    listOrdersAction(token);
    listUseCasesAction(account.id, token);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { account, orderList, progress } = state;
  const orders = orderList.get('orders');
  const platformMap = orderList.get('platformMap');
  return { account, platformMap, orders, progress };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  listOrdersAction: listOrders,
  listUseCasesAction: listUseCases,
})(OrdersIndexContainer);
```

And here is the dumb component:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import { Toolbar } from 'react-data-grid/addons';
import { Data } from 'react-data-grid/addons';
import moment from 'moment';
import { SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT } from '../../config/app_config';
// import OrderWrapFormatter from './OrderWrapFormatter';

const TABLE_COLUMNS = [
  { key: 'cNumber', name: 'Customer #', width: 125 },
  { key: 'name', name: 'Name', width: 150 },
  { key: 'orderNumber', name: 'Order #', width: 90 },
  { key: 'platform', name: 'Platform' },
  { key: 'useCase', name: 'Use Case'/* , formatter: OrderWrapFormatter */ },
  { key: 'list', name: 'List' },
  { key: 'sku', name: 'SKU' },
  { key: 'startDate', name: 'Start Date' },
  { key: 'endDate', name: 'End Date' },
];

export default class OrdersIndex extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    orders: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    platformMap: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    progress: PropTypes.number,
  };

  state = {
    rows: [],
    originalRows: [],
    columns: TABLE_COLUMNS,
    sortColumn: null,
    sortDirection: null,
    filters: {},
  }

  renderRows = (orders) => {
    const _rows = [];
    orders.map((o) => {
      _rows.push({
        key: o.order.id,
        id: o.order.id,
        cNumber: o.order.providerCustomerNumber,
        name: o.order.company.name,
        orderNumber: o.order.providerOrderNumber,
        platform: o.platformUseCases[0].platform.description,
        useCase: this.renderMulti(o.platformUseCases, 'useCase', 'description'),
        list: this.renderMulti(o.listSKUs, 'dataSet', 'name'),
        sku: this.renderMulti(o.listSKUs, 'fieldSet', 'name'),
        startDate: moment(o.order.startDate).format(SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT),
        endDate: moment(o.order.endDate).format(SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT),
      });
      return _rows;
    });
    return this.setState({
      rows: _rows,
      originalRows: _rows.slice(),
    });
  }

  getRows = () => {
    return Data.Selectors.getRows(this.state);
  }

  rowGetter = (rowIdx) => {
    const rows = this.getRows();
    return rows[rowIdx];
  }

  getSize = () => {
    return this.getRows().length;
  }

  renderMulti = (multi, itemName, subItemName) => {
    const objectArray = multi.map((object) => {
      return object[itemName][subItemName];
    });

    return objectArray.join('\n');
  }

  handleGridSort = (sortColumn, sortDirection) => {
    const { originalRows, rows } = this.state;

    const comparer = (a, b) => {
      if (sortDirection === 'ASC') {
        return (a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]) ? 1 : -1;
      }
      else if (sortDirection === 'DESC') {
        return (a[sortColumn] < b[sortColumn]) ? 1 : -1;
      }
    };
    const newRows = sortDirection === 'NONE' ? originalRows.slice() : rows.sort(comparer);
    this.setState({
      rows: newRows,
    });
  }

  handleRowUpdated = (e) => {
    // merge updated row with current row and rerender by setting state
    const { rows } = this.state;
    Object.assign(rows[e.rowIdx], e.updated);
    this.setState({
      ...rows,
    });
  }

  handleFilterChange = (filter) => {
    const { filters } = this.state;
    const newFilters = Object.assign({}, filters);
    if (filter.filterTerm) {
      newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
    }
    else {
      delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
    }
    this.setState({
      filters: newFilters,
    });
  }

  onClearFilters = () => {
    // all filters removed
    this.setState({
      filters: {},
    });
  }

  // Creates appropriate warnings to prevent entering
  // the order form if the account is missing information
  renderNotice = (message, buttonMessage, route) => {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>Notice:</strong>
        <p>{ message }</p>
        <p>
          <Link
            to={ route }
            className="btn btn-warning"
          >
            <i className='fa fa-plus'></i>
            { buttonMessage }
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { platformMap, progress } = this.props;
    const platformMessage = 'Your account is not associated with any platform use cases.' +
     'You must select at least one use case before creating new orders.';
    const platformButton = 'Add Use Cases';
    const platformRoute = '/products';

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
            <h1>Orders</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <span className="pull-right">
              <Link
                to="/orders/create/1"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                disabled
              >
                <i className='fa fa-plus'></i>Create New Order
              </Link>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        { platformMap.size === 0 && progress === 0 ?
          this.renderNotice(platformMessage, platformButton, platformRoute) : null }
        <div className="row">
          { progress === 0 ?
          <div className="col-md-12">
            { this.renderTable() }
          </div> : null }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderTable = () => {
    const { orders } = this.props;
    const { columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      { orders.size === 0 || orders === undefined ?
        <p>Your account has no orders</p> :
        <ReactDataGrid
          onGridSort={ this.handleGridSort }
          rowKey="key"
          id="key"
          columns={ columns }
          rowGetter={ this.rowGetter }
          rowsCount={ this.getSize() }
          onRowUpdated={ this.handleRowUpdated }
          toolbar={ <Toolbar enableFilter /> }
          onAddFilter={ this.handleFilterChange }
          onClearFilters={ this.onClearFilters }
          minHeight={ 500 }
          filterRowsButtonText="Search By Field"
        />
      }
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    const { orders } = this.props;

    const columnArray =
      TABLE_COLUMNS.map((c) => {
        const copy = Object.assign({}, c);
        copy.filterable = true;
        copy.locked = true;
        if (copy.key !== 'useCase') {
          copy.sortable = true;
        }
        return copy;
      });

    this.setState({
      columns: columnArray,
    });

    this.renderRows(orders);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    const { orders } = nextProps;
    if (orders.size > 0) {
      this.renderRows(orders);
    }
  }
}
```

I understand this might be a lot but I cannot for the life of me determine what could be the cause. Thanks to anyone who takes a look.

Comment: It's a lot of code. At a glance I didn't see anything suspicious (async code). I think you just need to walk through the exercise of stripping code until you isolate the problem area.

Comment: yeah i understand

Comment: Took some time to do what you said and found out when i commented out the react-data-grid this seemed to not throw the error.

Comment: Try removing your handlers (`onRowUpdated`) and if you still get the error I would say its likely a bug in `react-data-grid`, not your code. You might try logging an issue against `react-data-grid`.

Comment: yeah i did remove it and i still got the error. I will let react-data-grid know. Thanks for your help.